# How to get this image border effect with CSS

Tags: css

The border around "In Focus" and around the box. To put it simple. How do I recreate this on CSS. Taken from theatlantic.com.

[image]

Comment: please provide your html and css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

**CSS:**

```css
div.box
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 120px;
    position: relative;
    background: #CCC;
}

div.box > span
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    border-left: 1px solid red;
}

div.box > span + span
{
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 1px solid red;
    margin-left: -20px;
}

div.box > span + span + span
{
    top: 100%;
    left: 100%;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    margin-top: -20px;
}

div.box > span + span + span + span
{
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    border-right: none;
    border-left: 1px solid red;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="box">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>

    Hello.
</div>
```

---

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bWuXd/1/).

Comment: Thanks. close to what I was looking for, I can do the necessary modification from this. Cheers!